# Echo during SAS loop

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and am working on a very simple for loop.  In order to get a better understanding my code, I want to output the counter variable `i`, `product`, and `location` for each iteration within the loop.  How can I adjust my code to do this?  Every time I use either `put`, or `echo`, I end up with a syntax error.

```
data Error_log;
set Data_Set;

    do i=1 to nobs until (found);
        set Excel_Table point = i nobs = nobs;
        if (product = 01) and (Location = 'CA') then do;
            output Error_log;
            found = 1;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Whats the syntax error? Also believe the options should be in parenthesis  (point= nobs=). Also think the point= option require a stop statement aswell which you don't seem to have. I also suggest you change the variable name nobs to something else like nobs=My_Nobs.

Comment: why that double set statement?
can you please provide us a sample dataset for data_set and excel_table and also detail what you want your program to do? If data_set is useless, simply don't include it.
Also, your loop can't start, it is referred with a variable that has no value until second step statement, where nobs=nobs is not a valid option.

Comment: Also, why looping to the entire dataset? This is exactly what a datastep does without any loop...

Comment: If you're reading in from `Excel_Table` how about using `set Excel_Table(where=(product=01 and location='CA'));`?

Comment: @Jonas The point= nobs= options should NOT be in parentheses.  They are options to the SET statement, not dataset options.  While the STOP statement is often used with the point option, it is not required.  As written, the DATA step will stop automatically when the first SET statement reads the end-of-file marker in DATA_SET.

Comment: @stat Using two set statements like that is a common approach to reading specific rows from a second table while still iterating over the first table.  It's not usually used by people new to SAS but it's still a very valid approach.

Comment: In an attempt to reconcile the different points of view here: What you're doing above is not _wrong_, necessarily, and can be an interesting method to accomplish match-merging.  It is, however, a bit odd to see from someone new to SAS (as it's an unusual thing to do), and makes me (and some of the others here) think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the data step loop.  As you've done it now, you've got a cartesian product of the tables, which is really quite dangerous from a size point of view: is that the point of the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've gotten good advice from others already.  I think your exploration of SAS DATA step looping is a good idea.  There are definitely situations where having two set statements is useful, and explicitly iterating over a dataset with a DO loop is useful.  Google papers on "DoW loop" for reviews.  The PUT statement is useful for tracing loops.  Please show how you are trying to use it, and getting an error.

Below is a DATA step like yours, with a PUT statement added.  Note that I'm not trying to assess the intended logic of your code, or below code.  It's just an example of playing with looping.  `_n_` is a counter of the number of iterations of the implicit DATA step loop.

```
data Error_Log;
  set sashelp.class;
  do i=1 to nobs until(found);
    set sashelp.shoes point=i nobs=nobs;
    put (_n_ i name product subsidiary)(=);
    if product="Boot" and subsidiary="Cairo" then do;     
      output Error_log;
      found=1;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two quick points: As stat mentioned, it's not clear why you have the two set statements. Also, your `found=1` won't be captured as it is after the `output Error_log;`.

Regarding your question of how to get a better understanding of what's happening in your code you can use the `/debug` option on your dataset:

```
data Error_log / debug ;
set Data_Set;

    do i=1 to nobs until (found);
        set Excel_Table point = i nobs = nobs;
        if (product = 01) and (Location = 'CA') then do;
            output Error_log;
            found = 1;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

You can read more about it [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000379345.htm)

Otherwise, if `data_set` isn't needed, you could just return the 'found' records from `Excel_Table`:

```
data error_log ;
  set Excel_Table(where=(product=01 and location='CA'));
  found=1 ;
run ;
```

Comment: Note that /debug option, which triggers the DATA step debugger, is not available in Enterprise Guide or other environments that do not have an interactive session.  It's a great suggestion if you are using Display Manager SAS.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your PUT statement referenced a variable before it had been defined and caused SAS to define the variable in a way that did not match how it was defined in one of the input datasets. Here is an example.

```
data _null_;
   put name= ;
   set sashelp.class ;
run;

ERROR: Variable name has been defined as both character and numeric.
```

One way to prevent that is to add a line that includes a SET statement that can never be executed. That way SAS will check the referenced datasets and define the variables appropriately.

```
data Error_log;
  if 1=0 then set Data_Set Excel_Table ;
  length i found 8;
  put 'BEFORE first SET statement: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
  set Data_Set;
  put 'AFTER first SET statement: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
  do i=1 to nobs until (found);
    put 'BEFORE second SET statement: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
    set Excel_Table point = i nobs = nobs;
    put 'AFTER second SET statement: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
    if (product = 01) and (Location = 'CA') then do;
      output Error_log;
      found = 1;
    end;
    put 'AFTER IF statement: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
  end;
  put 'END of DATA step: ' (_n_ nobs i found product location) (=);
run;
```